# Can I include php file in .tpl?

Tags: php, opencart

Can I include a php file to tpl?

All I need is data from the database. I tried with `required('path/file.php')` but without success.

I already have controller for that. I need to include controller/file, class/php extension anything just need in tpl. I use OpenCart version 2.3.

Comment: a classic case of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

if you need data from the database, in `MVC` a model should be used, and then let the controller add it's data to the `$data` array, which the is available to the template.

this shows how OpenCart actually works ([source](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/model-view-controller-mvc-explained-through-ordering-drinks-at-the-bar-efcba6255053)):

[image: MVC diagram]

now tell me how your attempt to change a template (view) fits into there (notice the vertical lines).

---

just load the model into the controller and add results to `$data`, then it's available in the template.

Comment: I already have this model and controller but written for another template(tpl).
Now I want this data in this tpl file. For me the nicest way would be to include file php but how to tpl? That is question.

Comment: @AlexAl one does not write models or controllers "for" a template; these entities are independent.

Comment: `<?php require_once('path/file.php'); ?>` should work (because v2 is not Twig, but a custom template engine). nevertheless it's not meant to query the database from within the template.

Comment: if you need just data from database you not need to use opencart or something else structure.. There is how: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @K.B. feel free to post your own answer, so I can down-vote it... this is non-sense, because one should not start to write another application within a given framework. doesn't the image nicely show how it works?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I  voted up your answer, because someone without any reason voted down. So please explain  what exactly you want to say asking me to write my own answer? There is no answer, because main question is  not very understandable...

Comment: @K.B. that question is pretty simple, it just fails to realize the actual problem... and what I'm trying to tell is, that it's pointless to use a framework, while not using it (as it would be, when mixing up sequential code with OOP MVC, as the rest of the script uses it)... and there already is a database driver in place. also the linked article explains the situation.

Answer (score -2):

You should not directly mix templates with custom PHP code, even if in some template engines it's possible.

You should rather look into means of providing your PHP logic through functions, filters or macros. This way you make your PHP code available in templates.

If OpenCart uses twig, you could look into how to do such in the [documentation about extending twig here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html).

Comment: it is stated that it's `OpenCart version 2.3`... which does not use Twig, yet.